# $\operatorname{PSL}_n$ as an algebraic group

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let us fix some field and define every group over that field.

My doubt pretty simply is: Is $\operatorname{PSL}_n$ an algebraic group.

$\operatorname{PSL}_n$ is simply defined as $\operatorname{SL}_n$ quotiented by the subgroup made up of all matrices of the form $\lambda I_n$, where $\lambda^n = 1$ and $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Isn't this just the adjoint group of $\operatorname{SL}_n$? So, shouldn't this be representable.

I ask this question because the [Wikipedia page for Projective linear group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) states the following:

> As defined, the functor $\operatorname{PSL}(n,K)$ does not define an algebraic group, or even an fppf sheaf, and its sheafification in the fppf topology is in fact $\operatorname{PGL}(n,K)$.

Comment: You may find [this question at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16145/what-is-the-difference-between-psl-2-and-pgl-2) helpful. In short, there are explicit examples of the failure of representability for PSL.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks. This is helpful. So, would it right to say that $\operatorname{PGL}_n$ is the adjoint group of $\operatorname{SL}_n$?

Comment: If your adjoint group is the same as the dual group, yes. But I'm not so clear on the differences between adjoint and dual groups - these were on my quals way back when, but my work has not seriously involved algebraic groups for a while.

Comment: @KReiser adjoint groups and dual groups are very different in general. But yes, the adjoint group of SL(n) is PGL(n); it is the fppf sheafification of PSL(n). In general, the adjoint group of a reductive group G is the fppf sheafification of G/Z, where Z is the center of G.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @KentaS do you have a source for the fppf sheafification of $G/Z$ being the adjoint of $G$ maybe?